# Retrieve text from div and place into form input

Tags: javascript, html

```
   <div id="embeddedExample">
        <div id="embeddedCalendar">
        </div>
        <br/>
        <div id="embeddedDateField" class="dateField">
            Select a date from the calendar above.
        </div>
        <br/>
    </div>
```

I want to retrieve the current text from the div with id "embeddedDateField" and then put it into the following form:

```
<input id="dateInput" type="text" th:field="*{selectedDate}" style=""/>
```

I'm using this JS right now:

```
<script>
    // Access the input inside the div with this selector:
    $(function () {
      var myDate = $("#embeddedDateField").val();
      $("#dateInput").val(myDate);
      Console.log(myDate);
    });
</script>
```

The text is not appearing. What's wrong?

Comment: A `div` cannot have a `val()`. You would use `text()` for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uset `.text()` to retrieve text content of a div and not `.val()`. `.val()` is used for input elements..

```
    $(function () {
      var myDate = $("#embeddedDateField").text();
      $("#dateInput").val(myDate);
    });
```

Comment: Cool. This worked. Is there a simple way to listen for a change in the embeddedDateField?

Comment: Use `$("#dateInput").on("input", function(){ ... });` to listen the input change, but it wont work when you will change the value programatically. Please mark the answer correct if it solves your problem.. :)